# How to control what Worklight changes in auto generated html file?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How do I keep Worklight from making changes in the .html file that break things in the iPhone app?  Or at least, how can I control what it changes?

I'm using IBM Worklight 6.1.  After generating an iPhone environment I do the following:

1. "Run as-> Build iPhone Environment"
2. Then Worklight copies myApp.html from the common directory to the iPhone/native/www/default directory
3. Then Worklight makes changes to the original myApp.html file that causes my iPhone app to fail.

I've tried deleting all the code in /native, then do a "run as...build...", but still there are changes made to the html file that break the app.

Example of some things that get changed from the original /common/app.html file:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

gets changed to this:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<META content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

It also adds an extra (redundant) line of this:

```
<link href="worklight/worklight.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So I end up with:

```
<link href="worklight/worklight.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="worklight/worklight.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Using Eclipse Keplar with Worklight6.1

Comment: It appears that the html file had been taken from the /native and put back into /common which causes redundant entries.  So, started over and made sure I started with a clean /native html file.  Answer below is correct, there seems to be no way to control what is edited changed to the common/html file to the /native dir for the given environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce this problem in my environment (Eclipse Kepler (4.3.1.v20130911-1000), Worklight Studio 6.1 (6.1.0.00-20131126-0620) ).

Can you tell us what version of Worklight Studio you are using, and what version of Eclipse you are using?

The direct answer to your question is that there are no controls that let you influence what Worklight Studio changes in the HTML file when it copies it to the native environment - but, it should not be necessary to do this.